# How do I convert a tuple within a list (within a tuple) to a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I looked around and couldn't really find anything that I thought would help.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
xy = (event.xdata, event.ydata)
a = self.charges.get_charges()
a[self.closest_k][1] = xy
```

I'm messing around with a GUI and my problem is that I need to "move" the location of an object on the GUI with the position of my cursor.
xy returns the pair of co-ordinates that I need as an array, `self.closest_k` returns a number (there are a number of objects, and `self.closest_k` returns the index of the object I am trying to move).

```
a = [(1.0, array([ 1.,  0.])), (1.0, array([-1.,  0.])), (-1.0, array([ 0., -1.])), (-1.0, array([ 0., -1.]))]
```

The problem is that tuples are immutable, and since this is an assignment I am not allowed to change the function `get_charges()`. Beforehand I replaced:

```
a = self.charges.get_charges()
a[self.closest_k][1] = xy
```

with:

```
self.charges._pos[self.closest_k, :] = xy
```

But upon doing the Static Code Analysis I obtain the warning message `MyMplWidget.on_mouse_move: Access to a protected member _pos of a client class`. So I wanted to ask for a way around this, I thought about converting the tuple to a list but that doesn't convert the tuple within the tuple to a list.

Edit 1:

Okay, that is an improvement to what I had previously. Running the code doesn't return errors whenever I try to drag the object. This is what happens:

```
[(1.0, array([ 1.,  0.])), (1.0, array([-1.,  0.])), (-1.0, array([ 0., 1.])), (-1.0, array([ 0., -1.]))]
(-1.0, (-0.00071672257102850523, -1.5525644333591355))
```

So, I was trying to drag the object that had an original position [0, -1], and in doing so it's almost as if a new element of the list was created, it overwrites the original position as I am dragging, but as soon as I stop dragging the object resumes its original position.

```
(-1.0, (-0.00071672257102850523, -1.609902239041312))
(-1.0, array([ 0., -1.]))
```

In that example I was dragging the object with original position [0, -1]. As soon as I released the object it resumed its original position. (This isn't actually shown on the GUI, the object doesn't move at all but that's a problem with a different function that I can deal with).
I think the way my coding works at the moment, with regards to plotting the GUI, is that the function that deals with plotting the location of the object, expects its original location to change. But the original location is kind of "locked" inside of a tuple (sorry for the bad terminology). I guess I don't really know what to do about that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, I think you should just be replacing the entire element, instead of trying to modify one entry in the inner tuple. So

```
a[self.closest_k] = (a[self.closest_k][0], xy)
```